# How to create shaded regions following a rule across multiple facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

There are a few previous posts on how to make shaded regions in ggplot2 using geom_rect() but none of them help to create those shaded regions programmatically across facets. A good answer to my question would be very powerful and helpful for anyone wishing to graph unit-specific periods in panel data.

The closest ggplot2 example I could find is here, which displays shaded regions for recessions in an economic time-series graph, but I was unable to make this strategy work with facet_wrap.

I would like to make exactly [these](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/recession-bars/) kinds of shaded regions but programmatically across facets whenever a unit's dummy is equal to 0 (or 1).

Below is a reproducible example of panel data graphed in ggplot2 using facet_wrap(). The unit is firm and the time is year. The data has one dummy variable called "dummy". **My question is: How could one create shaded regions for the unit-specific periods in which a country's "dummy" is equal to 0. By implication, this would mean displaying unshaded regions when the country's dummy is equal to 1.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
require(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")
set.seed(888)
Grunfeld$dummy<-rbinom(200,1,prob=.3)

require(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(Grunfeld, id.vars=c("firm","year"))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfm) +
geom_line(aes(x=year, y=value, linetype=variable, colour=variable)) +
theme_bw() +
facet_wrap( ~ firm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `geom_rect()` and the unmelted `Grunfeld` data frame. Setting `ymax` to `Inf` and `ymin` to `-Inf` will make the shaded regions stretch from top to bottom. You also need to define `xmin` and `xmax`, which is easy here since you have a row for each year.

```
ggplot(dfm) +
    geom_rect(data = subset(Grunfeld, dummy == 0), 
              aes(ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, xmin = year-0.5, xmax = year+0.5), 
              alpha = 0.2)+
    geom_line(aes(x=year, y=value, linetype=variable, colour=variable)) +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap( ~ firm)
```